# Will the read/write of the 8 byte struct in these methods be atomic?

Tags: c#, optimization, atomic, volatile

I've been learning about atomic operations and C# alignment + atomicity guarantees. I want to see if I understand them correctly. Will the extension methods in the example be atomic, or is there something I'm not taking into account?

I think that other than the situation where the caller used unsafe code to misalign the `Point` reference in a 64 bit process, they should be atomic, right?

The example:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit, Size = 8)]
public struct Point
{
    [FieldOffset(0)]
    public float X;

    [FieldOffset(4)]
    public float Y;
}

public static class PointExtensions
{
    public static Point AtomicRead(this ref Point point)
    {
        unsafe
        {
            // this if will be compiled away
            if(sizeof(Point) != sizeof(long))
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException($"{nameof(Point)} must be the same size as {nameof(Int64)}");
            }
        }

        long data;

        // this if will be compiled away
        if (Environment.Is64BitProcess)
        {
            /**
             * Optimization to avoid calling cmpxchg8b or similar
             * 
             * If this is a 64 bit process, then reading a long value will be atomic since:
             *  - long is the word size
             *  - JIT ensures fields are aligned and don't straddle cache lines
             *  (this might not be atomic if the caller allocated the Point struct unaligned using unsafe code)
             * 
             * Also:
             * Part below could've been implemented as:
             * data = Unsafe.As<Point, long>(ref point);
             * Thread.MemoryBarrier();
             * 
             * .. but Volatile.Read seems better since it will only place the memory barrier if required
             */
            data = Volatile.Read(ref Unsafe.As<Point, long>(ref point));
        }
        else
        {
            // running 32 bit process, need to use Interlocked/cmpxchg8b to read atomically
            data = Interlocked.Read(ref Unsafe.As<Point, long>(ref point));
        }

        return Unsafe.As<long, Point>(ref data);
    }

    // similar reasoning as in AtomicRead() applies
    public static void AtomicWrite(this ref Point point, Point value)
    {
        unsafe
        {
            // this if will be compiled away
            if (sizeof(Point) != sizeof(long))
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException($"{nameof(Point)} must be the same size as {nameof(Int64)}");
            }
        }

        if (Environment.Is64BitProcess)
        {
            Volatile.Write(ref Unsafe.As<Point, long>(ref point), Unsafe.As<Point, long>(ref value));
        }
        else
        {
            Interlocked.Exchange(ref Unsafe.As<Point, long>(ref point), Unsafe.As<Point, long>(ref value));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The language specification doesn't make any guarantees here - int is guaranteed to be atomic, as are references, but it doesn't say "long will be atomic on 64-bit processes" or anything like that. Now: as an implementation detail, you'll probably be fine - but honestly, it depends what level of guaranteed correctness you need.

Comment: @MarcGravell It is a fair point that the specification doesn't explicitly guarantee long to be atomic, but the guarantee talks broadly about both 32 bit and 64 bit processes. My reasoning is that since a reference is always atomic, and 64 bit process references are 64 bits, long should be atomic too. Other questions/answers on stack overflow seem to agree with that logic. I guess the only way long wouldn't be atomic is if JIT didn't pad long fields the way it does other fields (like if struct of bool and long actually had size of 9 bytes), but I don't see why that would be the case.

Comment: again: if you want *an actual guarantee*: you need to comply to the spec, or use workarounds like `Interlocked.Read(ref long)`, or a `lock`, etc - to prevent torn reads; the *language* spec doesn't mention this scenario, so: you'd have to refer to the CLI spec